# Off Canvas Layout For Twitter BootStrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there any example of a "Off Canvas" layout using twitter bootstrap ?

I found one in [Foundation](http://www.zurb.com/playground/playground/off-canvas/offcanvas-4.html) and there is also this [CSS3 Experiment](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/offcanvas/technical/) but nothing for Twitter Bootstrap ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a generic example for "Off-Canvas" using twitter bootstrap:

http://codepen.io/krichnafsky/full/cuhkL

Feel free to use it.  If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 18):

I realize this question is old, but Twitter now includes an example of this with Bootstrap 3.0:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: yes, but they not yet give explanation how to did it.

Answer (score 3):

[This pull request](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6565) at the official github repo might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a generic example for "Off-Canvas" using twitter bootstrap:
>
> http://codepen.io/krichnafsky/full/cuhkL
>
> Feel free to use it. If you have any questions let me know.

Thats not a bad solution. Fairly simple. I would just add

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

so it doesn't add a bottom scroll bar while viewing the menu. Shouldn't need a bottom scroll bar anyway using bootstrap responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I also found another impressive [link](http://tech.xtremelabs.com/author/dforde/)

It would be great if I can get the collapsible menu to the right than the left