# Slide in Bootstrap collapsed menu from the left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

I found two different plugins, but neither is integrated into Bootstrap, and once they're implemented, there's a lot of buggy stuff going on. What I have tried so far: "**jQuery page slide**" and "**snap.js**"

page-slide appends to the `<div>` that you want to slide in and ends up removing all styles to your collapsed menu as well as all functionality for submenus.

Snap.js was definitely not developed with bootstrap in mind. The integration process is painful.

If anyone has accomplished this or if there is even a plugin for sale on code canyon please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this solution](http://codepen.io/krichnafsky/full/cuhkL) from [Off Canvas Layout For Twitter BootStrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563051/off-canvas-layout-for-twitter-bootstrap)
Credit to [krichnafsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1719542/krichnafsky)

Comment: Next time please provide source code, your answer isn't down yet but they might, like the other answer given.