# bootstrap- sticky side nav *outside* grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, nav

Okay. So i'm wireframing for responsive bootstrap, and received a request for a sticky side nav that lives outside of the 12 column grid - while still able to reposition for tablet and mobile. Is this even possible?

Management wants to use the full 12 columns for product, and have the nav stick to the outer edge. Could you do this with offset? Or are you 100% locked into the 12 columns only? I just want to make sure this is possible before I make any promises or work it into my design.

Thanks for any help or advice you can give!!

Comment: Are they talking about on canvas navigation? http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/step2.html (make your browser window small to see it)

Comment: Nope. On a maximized page, having your regular 12 column designed content, etc. then an *extra* three column nav that would stick to the side of the 12 column main body. sort of like this only sticky. http://www.sheplers.com/catalog/search.cmd?form_state=searchForm&keyword=boots&go=

Comment: Ok I think I got it. However, if you are making it responsive (I'd assume you'd use .row-fluid and .span1-.span12 in the default bootstrap css file) then the 12 columns add up to 100% width. If you want 12 columns for the content and then 3 additional columns for the nav, you would need a 15 column layout. If this is the case, you could use a tool like http://gridinator.com/ for a css template.

Comment: Crud. That's what I feared. So if I have this right, it's either jerry-rig it with hard coding, or carve out the space from existing real estate.

Comment: No problem! @Lara Olson

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to have the sticky nav in a regular span2 (or whatever) div and then the main body of the site in a nested column [More about nesting](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="span2">
<!-- sticky nav here -->
</div><!-- end span2 -->

<div class="span10>

<div class="row-fluid"> <!-- start nested column -->
<!-- main content here --> 
</div><!--end nested fluid-row -->

 </div><!--end span10 -->  

 </div><!--end parent row -->
  </div><!--end parent container -->
```

Depending on the specifics of your sticky nav, maybe you could use an off-canvas layout for the navbar as well.

[@krichnafsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1719542/krichnafsky) has a good bootstrap example of this @ [Off Canvas Layout For Twitter BootStrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563051/off-canvas-layout-for-twitter-bootstrap)

Good luck!

Comment: David - They have something in mind a little more like this: http://www.sheplers.com/catalog/search.cmd?form_state=searchForm&keyword=boots&go=

Comment: @LaraOlson Is the general layout a header at the top, fixed nav at the left, main content in the centre? Do you need the additional col on the right?

Comment: Yep! They are wanting 16 columns but the 12 column area to be the standard 1170 responsive. It looks like any option will take away from the main real estate unless we just code the extra tab into the side, which breaks the whole thing. After researching our user's standard monitor size, they tend to run small, so I'm not sure that the whole sticky side would be useful anyways in terms of viewable area. :(

Comment: >any option will take away from the main real estate ... yes @LaraOlson that's the drawback with anything in a side col. In practice it's either that, an off-canvas layout or move the side nav to a regular horizontal navbar above the main content.

Comment: Yeahhhh...with the amount of seo terms requested, it would be the horizontal banner that ate New York. lol. I'll have to push back on it, or demo why it's a bad idea. Thanks for the advice @DavidTaiaroa!!